# XHR Error (404) not found Angular 2

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I'm having issues loading a component. When I go to load another component, I get the following error

```
localhost/:22 Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/app/player-detail.component.ts.js(…)
```

My app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { PlayerDetailComponent } from './player-detail.component.ts';

@Component({
    selector: "my-app",
    templateUrl: 'app/views/app.component.html',
    directives: [PlayerDetailComponent],
})

export class AppComponent {
    title = "title";
}
```

Which according to the [tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/), looks correct

My main.ts:

```
import { bootstrap }    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

and my player-detail.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { Player } from './classes/player';

@Component({
    selector: "player-details",
    template: `<h2>Hello</h2>`,
})

export class PlayerDetailComponent {
    player: Player = {
        id: 1,
        name: "Test Player",
        email: "test@email.com",
        level: 0,
        maxHealth: 100,
        health: 100,
        maxEnergy: 100,
        energy: 100,
        fun: 1,
        skill: 1,
        knowledge: 1
    };

}
```

and my system.config.js:

```
(function(global) {

    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    var map = {
        'app':                        'app', // 'dist',
        'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs',
        'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
        '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular'
    };

    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    var packages = {
        'app':                        { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    };

    var packageNames = [
        '@angular/common',
        '@angular/compiler',
        '@angular/core',
        '@angular/http',
        '@angular/platform-browser',
        '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
        '@angular/router',
        '@angular/router-deprecated',
        '@angular/testing',
        '@angular/upgrade',
    ];

    // add package entries for angular packages in the form '@angular/common': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
    packageNames.forEach(function(pkgName) {
        packages[pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
    });

    var config = {
        map: map,
        packages: packages
    }

    // filterSystemConfig - index.html's chance to modify config before we register it.
    if (global.filterSystemConfig) { global.filterSystemConfig(config); }

    System.config(config);

})(this);
```

I have just been following the tutorial and changing some variable names and I really don't know why this error is popping up and I can't seem to find much about the error online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's because you are including the ".ts" extension in your import in your app.component.ts file. You want to remove that, I believe...

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { PlayerDetailComponent } from './player-detail.component';
```

Comment: Thanks. Always the small things

Comment: Happens to me all the time :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance the person who put the tutorial on the documentation page did not put the right version of the `systemjs.config.js` file. It turns out the section that defines the index file has a `.js` extension while the file used is `index.html`.

Change

`'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }`

to

`'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.html', defaultExtension: 'js' }`